# Loading using Ion Library returning null JsonObject result

Tags: java, android, android-ion

I had built an Android app a few months back, in which one fragment was used to display news using News API.
Recently, when I ran the app again, the following error is occurring.
[image: Error]

I am attaching the code snippet where the error is occurring.

```
Ion.with(getActivity()).load("GET",urltemp).asJsonObject().setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "enter ");
                    String status = result.get("status").getAsString();
                    if (status.equals("ok")) {

                        JsonArray array = result.get("articles").getAsJsonArray();

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                            JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

                            String author = object.get("author").toString();

                            String title = object.get("title").toString();
                            title = title.substring(1, title.length() - 1);

                            String url = object.get("url").toString();
                            url = url.substring(1, url.length() - 1);

                            String urlToImage = object.get("urlToImage").toString();
                            urlToImage = urlToImage.substring(1, urlToImage.length() - 1);

                            String date = object.get("publishedAt").toString();
                            String content = object.get("content").toString();
                            content = content.substring(1, content.length() - 1);

                            items.add(new ModelItems(title, author, date, urlToImage, url));
                        }

                        adapter = new SlideshowViewModel(getActivity(), items);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        Log.d(TAG, "success");
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "error");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Now, I thought there could be two possible sources of error, either it is a problem with URL(*urltemp* variable) or it is with Ion library. Now, I pasted the URL in the browser, it is working fine. So, I guess the problem is with Ion. The JsonObject result is null always. Tried different things, but can't figure out any solution.

I have never used Postman. So, I am not aware of how to post API response. I am attaching how i assigned URL.

[image: urltemp]

A thing I tried is pasting the above URL in the browser. When I paste the URL in browser, I get the following response:
[image: response]

Comment: can you post the error please!

Comment: click on Error(blue one)

Comment: It showing null cause your application isn't receiving a JSON String , CHeck where you connect to the server, And log that message if it's 200 then it's connecting else there's something wrong and your application isn't connecting to the server

Answer (score 0):

Seems like  `String status = result.get("status").getAsString();` is being returned null from your server. can you post a API response from postman

Comment: how about try logging the json result before enter tag

Comment: Log.d("result",result)

Comment: I tried Log.d("results", result.toString()) as writing only result showed error: Required String argument, provided JsonObject argument. But on writing result.toString(), same error occurs (Attempt to invoke virtual method toString() on null object reference".

Comment: I tried a different url from another API in load() method which didn't require api-key. It worked fine.

Comment: So now we know that your result is empty

Comment: I would suggest you place a debug point and run your app in debug mode